# Which is the best OS for web application development?

Tags: operating-system

Which is the best Operation System suited for web application development in various platforms  like JAVAEE, PHP, Ruby-On-Rails, Perl, Python, if I have missed out anything then that too etc. including testing front end and business logics, version control system like svn/git etc, planning, reporting, life cycle management etc etc? In short, need to cover all aspects for web application engineering.

I have  used both Windows and Linux and have felt Linux is better for its great command line capability. I have no idea about development in Mac. My experience in web application development is limited to 3 years and I just need expert opinion.

Comment: Perhaps spend some time researching yourself and come back with a more specific question that is programming related, rather then relying on someone else to do it for you

Comment: I'd agree with the comment above. It's a bit like asking what's the best car? Your specific needs may vary from mine. For what it's worth, Windows is best for me.

Comment: I had done some research and felt Linux is best for my purpose. But my experience is limited to 3 years and I just wanted some expert opinion.

Comment: I'm a Mac OS X fan. But that only indicates how subjective and argumentative this question is (or will quickly become). Voting to close. Pick whichever OS you want; there's no tangible reason that one is "better" than another. **You'll be *far* more productive sticking with the OS you're already familiar with than you will be switching to a different one, no matter how much "better" it seems to be on paper.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux is great option because of the following:

- Software/Tools availability
- Relatively easy troubleshooting
- Easy to find answers on any question/error code you get
- Great package management (Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives)
- Friendly community
- and many more

About the machine configuration more RAM, more HDD space, better CPU, ... :). In the company I work, every in-house developed piece of software is developed and hosted on Linux. I really can not remember of any issues we've had, except minor hardware related ones.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is always a best bet on development, but of course you'll want available testing platforms with Windows and Macintosh, as well as other Unix bases for testing to make sure that your product functions appropriately under all configurations.

Comment: If you don't build with asp.net at least